# Field Length limit using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, limitations

I am trying to create a text field in ArcGIS Pro 3.0 attribute table with 3000 - 5000 characters. I save and it defaults back to 254.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Erik:

> Shapefiles allow only for field lengths of 255 characters. You need to
> use a different file type.

and by @Vince:

> The hard limit on dBase III+ string length is 254, not 255, though
> it's not obvious why. Use file geodatabase, and your length won't
> change.